# Iterating through a list of commands in a file in Shell Programming

Tags: shell

I have a file containing a list of unix commands like "ls -la /etc/passwd". I want to iterate through this list of commands, and take appropriate action.

Currently, my code is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
for cmds in `cat /tmp/cmd`
do
        if [  $cmds ] ; then
                echo $cmds;
        fi
done
```

But, what I get is an output where the commands are broken up in different lines like

```
ls 
-la 
/etc/passwd
ls 
-la
/etc/shadow
```

and not

```
ls -la /etc/passwd
ls -la /etc/shadow
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before your for loop:

```
IFS='
'
```

Or in Bash:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

[`IFS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables) contains a list of characters which are used to split input into fields; it defaults to including spaces, tabs, and linefeeds, which was why you were getting the incorrect behavior. Setting it to a newline will only split on newlines, which is what you want.

Comment: Your solution partly worked, but all the n's were also used to split the input fields. And, it gave incorrect output like
 /etc/ssh/sshd_co
fig
svcs -a | grep 
etwork
etstat -a | grep -i liste

As you can see all n's were lost and incoorectly denoted new lines.

Comment: Sorry. It appears that my version of Bash interprets \n in IFS specially; in generally, though, that won't work for putting a newline into a string. I've edited my answer to be more portable; you can put a literal newline in the string, or use Bash's C-style quotation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can also do this (surround your backticks with double-quotes):

```
"`cat /tmp/cmds`"
```

Maybe try something like this (not sure what your "if" is supposed to be checking - I modified it to make sure the $cmds var was not empty string):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

for cmds in "`cat cmds.txt`"
do
    if [ "$cmds" != '' ]; then
        echo "$cmds"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I got an error after putting in the double quotes
/tmp/fo: line 6: [: too many arguments

Answer (score 2):

If each line in the file is a complete command - no continuations over multiple lines - then you can use `read`:

```
while read cmd
do
    if [ -z "$cmd" ]
    then : Empty
    elif $cmd
    then : OK
    else : Oops
    fi
done < cmds.txt
```

Or, if you prefer linear construction and don't need anything from the sub-shell that the while loop represents in what follows, you can use:

```
cat cmds.txt |
while read cmd
do
    if [ -z "$cmd" ]
    then : Empty
    elif $cmd
    then : OK
    else : Oops
    fi
done
```

Note the careful use of quotes around the tested string.  I still prefer to use an explicit '`-z`' operator; there are those who argue it is not 100% necessary.  I still use single square brackets rather than double - mainly out of habit built up over 20+ years.  Those who learned shell using `bash` or `ksh` often prefer the double square bracket operator instead.

Beware I/O redirections, of course.

Also, if you don't have anything to do in the various then and else clauses, you should simply feed cmds.txt to the shell:

```
sh cmds.txt
```

This is by far the most reliable way of dealing with multi-line commands.